# why i cant get an axios response in react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

so I'm having a problem getting data from my server to my front-end using axios.

as you can see in this picture I'm getting a response for the GET method for users/users.

[image]

this is my showUsers function

```
const showUsers = async (req, res) => {
 await User.find({})
   .then((user) => {
  res.status(200).json(user);
})
.catch((error) => {
  res.status(400).send(error);
});
};
```

this is my axios api export

```
import axios from "axios";

 export default axios.create({
 baseUrl: "http://localhost:8080/users",
 });
```

and this is my useEffect

```
import api from "../api/users";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const LogIn = (props) => {
  const { setIsNewMember } = props;
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUsers = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await api.get("/users");
        setUsers(response.data);
      } catch (err) {
        if (err.response) {
          console.log(err.response.data);
          console.log(err.response.status);
          console.log(err.response.headers);
        } else {
          console.log(`Error: ${err.message}`);
        }
      }
    };

    fetchUsers();
  }, []);
```

I'm getting this error on the frontend

[image]

so although I'm getting it from the postman and other services I'm not getting it on the front.

any idea why is that happening?

Comment: **Just a typo**. The Axios property you want is `baseURL` (case is important). See https://axios-http.com/docs/instance

Comment: I cant believe i wasted 2 hours on a typo. Thank Phil, appreciate it.